# asp.net framework 4.7 configure logging level, not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-webjobs

My web job is not adhering to the logging level configuration in my host.json. It is written using .NET framework 4.7. The expected result with the below code is no logging, instead, I get logging a per the below screenshot. Can any provide guidance on how to fix this? Do I need to add additional configuration/startup code?

[image]

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "Functions.Test": "None",
      "default": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

C# Web Job Code

```
public static void Main()

        {

            var config = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            var builder = new HostBuilder();

            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddTimers();
                b.AddBuiltInBindings();
            });

            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
            });

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                var jobHost = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IJobHost)) as JobHost;
                jobHost.CallAsync("Test").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Functions
    {
        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void Test(ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogCritical("LogCritical");
            logger.LogDebug("LogDebug");
            logger.LogError("LogError");
            logger.LogInformation("LogInformation");
            logger.LogTrace("LogTrace");
            logger.LogWarning("LogWarning");
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting `fileLoggingMode` to `never`. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging

Comment: This, unfortunately, makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for sharing your code.

It seems to me that in the first statement
a config object is being built `var config = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder()...`, however, later in the code this `config` variable is not used while host creation and configuration. As a result, those settings are not applied and default `Information` logLevel is used.

We need to supply this configuration to the `HostBuilder`, looks like it can be done using `HostBuilder`'s `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method. Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970969/how-to-use-hostbuilder-for-webjob), it has an example how to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately, I get the same result when using this code instead. Any other thoughts?

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var builder = new HostBuilder();

            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(cb => cb

               //  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

                 .AddJsonFile("host.json")

            );

Comment: One thing is to double check that it actually finds `host.json`, you can specify `optional: false` in `AddJsonFile` method

Comment: I ran process mon to confirm the host.json file is being opened. as well as setting optional: false. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: We can try to rename `host.json` to `appsettings.json` since `ConfigureWebJobs` adds this config file by default.
Also, we can try to change the order of `ConfigureWebJobs` and `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, looks like `ConfigureWebJobs` should go first.
Please take a look at this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1931

Comment: If I add the b.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace); line to configure logging method then I get trace level logging. I have confirmed that the host.json file is being loaded, so my theory is the host.json file is not applied for .net Framework 4.7 web jobs or the host.json file is not correctly formatted. Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out the github issue shared above? If yes, please let me know why it's not applicable to your case.

Comment: Yes I also rearranged the code to have ConfigureWebJob execute first followed by ConfigureAppConfiguration. I also renamed the host.json to appsettings.json